# Some problems after installing Windows 10 on iMac

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver

I installed windows 10 two days ago on my iMac 2011 21.5 inch with drivers from bootcamp. Unfortunately, I don't have sound and I don't have 1920x1080 screen resolution :(

My question is: What i need to do to repair this?
And if i need to install other bootcamp drivers, how do I delete the old bootcamp?

Comment: Drivers may not exist - that machine isn't supported for Win 10 in Boot Camp - see https://support.apple.com/HT204990

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a driver issue. I suggest reinstalling Bootcamp from Apple's website.

1. If you aren't currently in the Windows 10 partition, restart the computer and navigate into Windows 10.
2. Download this from Apple's website (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

> This download is specific to your 2011 iMac but you can easily find
>   downloads for other macs by navigating to support.apple.com/downloads
>   and searching for "bootcamp". To determine if a bootcamp package is compatible, look under the "system requirements" link.

3. Extract the zip file to your directory of choice.
4. Navigate to `BootCamp5.0.5033\BootCamp\setup.exe` and run the setup.exe file
5. Close all other programs while this runs.
6. After the installer completes, restart the computer and reenter Windows 10
7. To ensure the latest drivers and software, run Apple Software update from within Windows 10.

Hope this helps you. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I downloaded Bootcamp but I got an error : A newer version of Bootcamp is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. So what I need to do ?

Comment: Can you tell me what version of Bootcamp is installed currently? Reference "Apple iMac 24"s answer here (https://discussions.apple.com/message/11266215#message11266215) to learn how.

Comment: @tetsujin suggests Apple doesn't support Windows 10 with Bootcamp on your Mac. This article (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) also suggests it isn't compatible. How did you get Windows 10 on your mac? Did you once have Windows 7 installed an upgrade to Windows 10 from within Windows?

Comment: It sounds like a driver issue but it may be that some of your hardware isn't supported by Windows 10. You might look in the device manager. Navigate to "device manager" and look for any yellow (!). Those indicate missing drivers. See if you can post hardware information. It may be possible to find the drivers for your hardware without bootcamp.

Comment: Also, what operating system is your mac running?

Comment: You should update your question details with all of this information.

Comment: This post (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7165461?tstart=0) suggests that while your mac isn't officially supported, Windows 10 can run perfectly.

Comment: Hi, I fixed my resolution problem and i get the resolution of 1920x1080 but the only thing that does not work is the sound :(, how i can fix that ?

Comment: My BootCamp version is 6.0.1 and my OS is 10.11.6 El Capitan. I installed Windows 10 using USB key and ISO file with bootcamp.

Comment: @DayosS Congrats on the graphic driver. This is the last suggestion I
can think of if you can't find the audio driver: (1) boot into Windows
10. (2) Launch the settings app. (3) Go to "Update and Security". (4)
Navigate to "recovery" in the left side list. (5) Under "reset this
PC", click the "get started" button. (6) A dialogue will popup, select
"remove everything" (this will remove all of your personal files from
Windows 10 so BACK UP YOUR STUFF).... (continues in next comment)...

Comment: Your PC should restart several times as it resets. Each time, you will need to hold the `Option` key
and select your Windows 10 partition to continue the installation.
After you have reinstalled, try downloading and installing Bootcamp 5
(https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).
Extract the download and look for setup.exe. After it installs, you
will need to restart again. Go back into Windows 10 and run Apple
Software Update and it will update to the latest version of bootcamp.
It should work. Let me know what happens :)

Comment: I did everything you said but unfortunately, nothing has changed and the sound still does not work and i don't have AMD Catalyst so my resolution is broken :(

Comment: But it's may be possible to find drivers without BootCamp ?

Comment: I think I'll have to install windows 7 instead of 10 :(

Comment: @DayosS You may find Windows 7 to be more stable. However, you might first try running the Windows Apple Software Update program. It will detect bootcamp and driver updates for you to install. Let me know what happens.

Comment: I tried to install Windows 7 but the problem is that the USB with the iso file is not recognized when i boot my Mac while Windows 10 iso file is recognized. So I can install only Windows 10 :(. Also, after i launched the Windows Apple Software Update program, it only downloaded the security update. Maybe another solution ?

Comment: Try going to the Windows 10 device manager. Look for any Yellow exclamation points. Try updating your drivers from there. Let me know what you see.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The problem is that the audio controller device have yellow exclamation point and do not want to get started ( in description ). But when I click on 'update', it said : the device is already updated. I think I need delete this and maybe search older driver ?

Comment: This device from microsoft is the only device who have exclamation point. I think this is the source of the sound problem because there is a red cross on the sound !

Comment: I also found another problem is that wifi with the latest version bootcamp is very slow but with the version you gave me, the speed of the connection has returned to normal :)

Comment: Great. If it says it's already installed, try "uninstalling" it and reinstalling. Double click on the entry in device manager to access these options. Tell me what happens :) glad it's working out. Is the display at the correct resolution?

Comment: I found another big problem is that the wifi on windows 10 became terribly slow after a few minutes. It's just impossible to use internet and install new drivers or programs now :(.

Comment: The display is at the correct resolution because i installed the AMD Catalyst driver.

Comment: Good regarding the resolution. For wifi, you can go into device manager and find the hardware ID of the wifi and search for the driver on another computer. Download and transfer the driver via USB. Hope it works. If not, you could try wiring the computer or connecting via Bluetooth. I can show you how to connect with Bluetooth. It's slow and unreliable but it is I internet. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is what i do, but i don't know how to find the audio controller driver because when i reinstalled it from the device manager, it did not work with yellow exclamation point.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 drivers on your Mac are essential to ensure your Mac runs properly on Windows 10. However, if the Mac drivers are outdated, missing, corrupted, damaged, or incompatible after a Windows 10 installation (or update), your Mac  and other devices connected to it will not work properly on Windows 10.

When it comes to Windows Bootcamp installations, I always take the approach that “if it ain’t broken, don't fix it”. In your case though, it's worth checking for driver issues. The best way to do this is by downloading and updating to the latest Mac drivers.  The two options I've seen used most often to achieve this are:

**Option 1** - Use the Apple Software Update for Windows to install any available driver updates for Windows 10. However, it doesn't always work well and I've read that some drivers are not available via this method. Also, you may need to be patient for it to update any necessary drivers as it can take hours. Because of these reasons, the next approach is often used.

**Option 2** - Use one of the many utilities that enable you to update drivers for Windows installations. [Driver Talent](http://www.drivethelife.com/) is one of these utilities and it can help repair any Mac drivers that are corrupted or damaged. It will also download and install any Windows 10 Mac drivers that are missing or outdated. Note there are both [free and pro versions](http://www.drivethelife.com/free-drivers-download-utility.html#comparison) available. However, the free version is all you should need.

**NOTE:** *I have no affiliation whatsoever with the Driver Talent software. I mention it only because I have seen it resolve issues with Windows Bootcamp installations.*

**Reset SMC**

Finally, I have seen instances where resetting the SMC actually helps in terms of VRAM and Bootcamp partitions (although this is a surprise to me, I've seen it with my own eyes). So, doing this *may* help in terms of your screen resolution, although ensuring you have the latest drivers (as described above) should resolve your issue. To reset the SMC on your iMac, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Unplug it from the power
3. Press and hold the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds
4. Plug it back in and turn it on.

**Useful resources** - You may find the following resource of interest:

- [Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204990)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 and 10 are designed to automatically find, download, and install drivers in the background for your device after an install. Double check in Settings -> Update and Security  that updates are automatically being installed. Updates can be large, so download speeds affect how quick this will be.

Often enough, you just have to connect to your network and wait it out.  Go to the update section in settings to check for updates if it suits you.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded all drivers from Microsoft updates, but I still have the same problems, no sound ...